# A number theoretical problem related to inverse sum of divisors

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If $n$ is a perfect number then its sum of divisors is $2n$. I would like to prove that $$\frac{1}{d_1}+\frac{1}{d_2}+\ldots+\frac{1}{d_{K}}=2$$ 
where $d_k$ are the divisors of $n$.

Comment: The sum of inverse divisors can be arbitrarily large, consider the case that $n$ is the factorial of some number $k$, its sum of inverse divisors contains the first $k$ terms of the harmonic series.

Comment: It's not true: it fails (at least) for every prime number.

Comment: The question as edited makes no sense. I'd guess that the true question is to prove that the sum of the reciprocals of the divisors of a perfect number is equal to 2: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/594280/420432

Comment: Why the [geometry] tag? Please remove it.

Comment: use latex (click on edit)

Answer (score 2):

The correct statement is

> If $n$ is a perfect number, i.e. some $n\in\mathbb{N}^+$ such that
>   $\sum_{d\mid n}d=2n$, then $\sum_{d\mid n}\frac{1}{d}=2$.

And that is trivial: for any divisor $d$ there is a complementary divisor $\frac{n}{d}$ and

$$ \sum_{d\mid n}\frac{1}{d} = \sum_{d\mid n}\frac{1}{\frac{n}{d}} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{d\mid n}d = \frac{2n}{n}=2.$$

Comment: the OP's statement was very messy